# How do I count individual number of characters in a word from a text file?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment to read a text from a file and remove all of the words which have an odd number of characters. I don't really know where to start because I'm still learning the basics and could use some help. The biggest question I have is how do I count individual words. Like how would I seperate the counting from word to word in a text file. Thank you for the help

//Sorry for the lack of clarity, English is my second language and it can be difficult some times to specify what I need.

I have an assignment to write a c++ program where it:
(1)Reads a text file and determines which words are even and which are odd
(2)Then it takes even words and reverses the order of characters in each even word.

So for example I have a moderate size text. It picks out even words and reverses their character order.

So far I have written this code and I don't know if it is any good to continue with because I don't know how to reverse the order of characters.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string word;
        ifstream f("text.txt");
        if (f.is_open())
        {
            while (f >> word)
            {
                if (word.length() % 2 == 0)
                    cout << word << endl;
            }
            f.close();
        }
            else
                cout << "file is not open" << '\n';
        }
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Have you any code? Then share it. And for phrasing, you want to count the characters in single words, not the words at all?

Comment: split the taks into small managable parts, then try to do them in steps. For each part of the problem you can find Q&As here and if not you can ask a speficic question. Currently your question is too broad

Comment: 1. Read words from file, one by one. 2. Check each word as you read it. 3. Write to new file if it's a word you want. 4. Once done, close both files and rename new file to original file.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. Do you want to count the number of words in a file ? Do you want to count the number of characters in each word ? Do you want to count the number of words that are composed of a fixed number of characters ? Edit your question to tell me that, please.

Comment: @Apitronix "I have an assignment to read a text from a file and remove all of the words which have an odd number of characters." Not being clear about what is OPs task isn't really the problem of this question

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yep, misread. I think (after edits (2 days ago from now)) this question should be reopen, no ?

Comment: @Apitronix dont ask me, I am not the one to tell others to vote for reopen ;). Fwiw, I read the question again and decided not to vote for reopening, because there is still no question, which makes it difficult to answer without simply dropping the code